# Backbone.js not working with Require.js bundle

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, requirejs

I can't get Backbone.js to play nicely with require.js' bundle system.

**This works:**

```
requirejs.config({
    baseUrl: 'assets/',
    bundles: {
        corejs: ['jquery', 'underscore']
    },
    paths: {
        corejs: '../core',
        jquery: '../static/js/jquery',
        backbone: '../static/js/backbone',
        underscore: '../static/js/underscore',
        knockout: '../static/js/knockout',
        knockback: '../static/js/knockback'
    },
    shim: {
        backbone: {
            deps: ['underscore', 'jquery'],
            exports: 'Backbone'
        }
    },
    deps: ['corejs']
});

require(['app/app'], function(App) {
    App.initialize();
});
```

Changing `bundles` to be

```
bundles: {
    corejs: ['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone']
}
```

**results in a require.js timeout**

core.js currently consists of concatted jQuery, Underscore, Backbone

Backbone is available on the browser console, even before the timeout.

Comment: Since [1.1.1](http://backbonejs.org/#changelog) backbone supports AMD and CommonJS out of the box so you don't need to shim it if using a newer version.

Answer (score 0):

As @ivarni mentioned in the comments, Backboone has had CommonJS support added:

```
// Next for Node.js or CommonJS. jQuery may not be needed as a module.
} else if (typeof exports !== 'undefined') {
    var _ = require('underscore'), $;
    try { $ = require('jquery'); } catch(e) {}
    factory(root, exports, _, $);
```

which means that if you use a recent version of Backbone you can just `require` it normally without having to create a shim.